# TSQL Continuous Counters

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Given:
Table A with fields F1, F2, F3, first two fields are ints, last is varchar. 
F1 unique, F2 and F3 can container any values

```
F1  F2  F3
==========
1   1   A
2   1   A
3   1   A
9   1   B
19  2   B
20  2   C
29  2   C
34  2   B
35  2   A
36  2   A
37  2   A
49  2   A
```

I need to produce counters for for each combination of F2 and F3 for continues ranges of F1 in the following format:

```
Start Count F2 F3
=================
1     3     1  A
9     1     1  B
19    1     2  B
20    1     2  C
29    1     2  C
34    1     2  B
35    3     2  A
49    1     2  A
```

I know how to accomplish the task using a cursor, wonder if the result can be produced using just select statement?

**Update 1** - Sorry if it wasn't clear - I want the last interval for 2-A to be split by two because of the brake in F1.

Comment: Can we add (say) the `5,1,A` row to your sample data and result set so that it's a bit clearer?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right, brake in F1 must force a new counter, otherwise it would be a simple aggregate.

Comment: You may check my new solution. Thanks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
WITH MyCTE AS
(
  SELECT  T1.F1,
          T1.F2,
          T1.F3,
          ISNULL((
            SELECT TOP 1 F1
            FROM table1 AS x
            WHERE T1.F1 < x.F1 AND (T1.F3 = x.F3 AND T1.F2 = x.F2)
            ORDER BY F1 DESC
          ),0) AS grpby
  FROM    Table1 T1 
)

SELECT  MIN(F1) AS Start,
        COUNT(F1) AS [Count],
        F2,
        F3
FROM    MyCTE
GROUP BY F2,
        F3,
        grpby
ORDER BY 1
```

Here is a [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a0c6c/34)

Comment: That fits the expected results but I think that's because the sample data is rather limited. I believe that a row `5,1,A` should have a separate line in the result, rather than becoming part of the one with a `Start` value of 1.

Comment: Well, i think this is for the asker to determine.

Comment: @Damien I think that the statement "for each combination of F2 and F3" covers that though...

Comment: What of "continues" though (which I took to be an attempt to spell continuous)

Comment: The key here is not to group values with the same F2 and F3 is F1 has gaps - sorry I should have said that.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not working right. Add two blocks with the same F2, F3, but with gaps. 49 does not show up, and the count is compromised.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6b714/1

Comment: Not it isn't, F1 isn't kept unique - which is a quick way to check it, but I accepted it as answer as I can fine tune it myself.

Comment: Yeah, i noticed. Even if i put 7,1,A then i miss 5,1,A (which is counted as a part of 1,1,A).